# A BackgroundWorker returning null without Exception error when the same operations done outside of it return a value

Tags: c#, multithreading, null, backgroundworker

I have a few **BackgroundWorkers** all doing the same task in a **TabPage** : they pull data from a MySql database and upon completion they update the **BindingSource** of a **Chart**.

One of them started acting up lately. Here is the code:

```
private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable dT = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();

      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantTableAdapter.Fill(dT);
      e.Result = dT;
}

private trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable salesThisMonthDataTable = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();

private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      salesThisMonthDataTable = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();
      salesThisMonthDataTable = (trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable)e.Result;

      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.DataMember = "";
      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.DataSource = salesThisMonthDataTable; 
            
      // If the sales are null at the beginning of a month, the filter and sorting will throw an error
      if (e.Result!=null)
      {
          this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.Filter = "Total<>0 AND Vendeur<>'Total'";
          this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.Sort = "Total ASC";
      }

      this.chartSalespersonsThisMonth.DataSource = this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource;
      this.chartSalespersonsThisMonth.DataBind();
}
```

Now oddly enough, since I can't step through the ***BackgroundWorker_DoWork*** event, if I copy the code into the ***RunWorkerCompleted*** as shown below, then I get real data, not null.

```
private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      // Temporary fix for Background Worker e.Result which is null for some reason, with no Exception error thrown (e.Cancel and e.Error are both null)
      trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable dT = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();
      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantTableAdapter.Fill(dT);

      salesThisMonthDataTable = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();
      salesThisMonthDataTable = (trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable)e.Result;

      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.DataMember = "";
      this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.DataSource = dT;      // Temporary fix
            
      // If the sales are null at the beginning of a month, the filter and sorting will throw an error
      if (e.Result!=null)
      {
          this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.Filter = "Total<>0 AND Vendeur<>'Total'";
          this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource.Sort = "Total ASC";
      }

      this.chartSalespersonsThisMonth.DataSource = this.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource;
      this.chartSalespersonsThisMonth.DataBind();
}
```

How is this possible? How can the same code return a null value in one thread and a set of data in another?

The only changes I've made to the code lately in this section is the added `if (e.Result!=null)` section, because there was no data for the current month and when the *Sort* property was set, it would throw an exception error. But now there is data, it's just not seeing it. It's been working well for months. Other than this month being a new year, nothing else has changed. At first I thought the *MySQL View* was flawed, but nope.

Any thoughts on why or even how I can figure out where the problem is?

Comment: Why can't you step through BackgroundWorker_DoWork? You should be able to set a breakpoint at the start of the event handler. If necessary, you can freeze other threads in the debugger while stepping through that code.

Comment: Amen to the "freeze others" - I've often thought it'd be nice if VS colored the advancing yellow bar different color for different threads, to make it more obvious, when the code is jumping around like crazy, that you're looking at different threads stepping..

Comment: I'm all for descriptive variable names, but I think even I would have cut down `viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantBindingSource` a bit :) `trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable dT = new trimlineSalesReportDataSet.viewventesparutilisateurmoiscourantDataTable();
` is an inspiration for `var` too!

Comment: @EricJ. I tried setting a breakpoint but it just goes through the DoWork without breaking, event if I add a ```Debugger.Debug()```

Comment: The code seems odd; you generally don't need to do all this binding/unbinding/rebinding - just leave your things bound to the bindingsources (which are bound to the tables) theyre bound to and Fill the underlying table..

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point

Comment: What hapens with a test datagridview thrown onto the form? Drop one out of the datasources window and literally just have a BGW DoWork of `new SomeTableAdapter().Fill(theDataSet.TheTableForTheGridYouDroppedOnTheForm)` and then in the BGW RunWorkerCompleted do `TheBindingSourceThatAppearedWhenYouDroppedTheGrid.ResetBindings(false);`

Comment: *goes through the DoWork without breaking* - is the DoWork event still definitely bound to the method that implements it? You can eg drop a BGW on a form, double click its DoWork event, write some code, go back to form, double click its RunCompleted event, write some code, go back to prop grid events list and right click the DoWork / choose Reset to unlink the event handler code from the event.. Put breakpoints in Run/Work/Completed then click the button that RunAsync's the worker.. it'll skip right over the DoWork (because it's not wired up any more) and then run the WorkerCompleted code

Comment: @CaiusJard OK now I feel silly, that last comment you made had me go through the properties and for some ready the DoWork event was no longer bound to the BackgroundWorker. I don't know how that line of code disappeared, it just never occured to me since I don't recall having changed it, but that was it, and it should have been obvious when I wasn't able to step through it with the debugger. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be lying if I said "it's never happened to me" - the number of times I've spent ages setting up some test data at runtime, hit save, what.. why is this data not in the db.. spend X minutes finding out the darned save button click handler isn't bound any more.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagnosis of this one in comments under the question, turned out that the DoWork event handler code had become un-bound from the DoWork event. I've had this happen from time to time for various controls as I work with the designer..

The code lens for reference count can also be a hint to this:

[image]

Incidentally, I'd say your code might be collapsible to just this:

```
private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      e.Result = this.VenParMoisCourTableAdapter.GetData();
}

private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      this.VenParMoisCourBindingSource.DataSource = e.Result;
      
      this.VenParMoisCourBindingSource.Filter = "Total<>0 AND Vendeur<>'Total'";
      this.VenParMoisCourBindingSource.Sort = "Total ASC";
}
```

GetData should always return a datatable even if it's empty, so you might be able to skip the null check

Also, maybe you already know but you can always right click your TableAdapter in your dataset and add more queries that do other filtering so a query of

```
SELECT * FROM VenParMoisCour WHERE Total<>0 AND Vendeur<>'Total' ORDER BY Total
```

Would save those records being downloaded in the first place. Give the query a good name when asked, like FillAllExceptZeroTotal / GetDataByAllExceptZeroTotal and you can

```
private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      e.Result = this.VenParMoisCourTableAdapter.GetDataByAllExceptZeroTotal();
}

private void bgwRefreshChartMoisCourant_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      this.VenParMoisCourBindingSource.DataSource = e.Result;
}
```