# Groupbox visibility toggles between two but not third groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a WindowsFormApp that has a Menu Strip that contains three options. What I want to do is have 3 groupboxes, though only one being Visible at start and when the respective option has been clicked in the MenuStrip, it toggles between the 3 groupboxes by toggling their visibility. Right now groupbox1 is visible on the start of the program but I can only then toggle between groupbox2 & groupbox3. Once I switch to groupbox2 or groupbox3, I can no longer switch back to groupbox1.

Here is a minimal code of what I've done so far:

```
        private void show1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            groupBox2.Visible = !groupBox1.Visible;
            groupBox3.Visible = !groupBox1.Visible;

        }

        private void show2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox2.Visible = true;
            groupBox1.Visible = !groupBox2.Visible;
            groupBox3.Visible = !groupBox2.Visible;
        }

        private void show3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox3.Visible = true;
            groupBox1.Visible = !groupBox3.Visible;
            groupBox2.Visible = !groupBox3.Visible;
        }
```

I have already created items in groupboxes and set groupbox1 visibility to true while 2 and 3 remains false.

Comment: Sounds to me like `show1ToolStripMenuItem_Click` has become no-longer-bound to the Click event of menu strip 1 - that is to say that groupbox1 is only ever visible because it is visible at form startup,  and clicking the menu item never fires the code that would make gb1 visible again. The other two handlers are bound fine. Controls on forms do sometimes lose their event handler bindings; I think it happens to me from time to time when I cut and paste the control

Comment: Have a look at the code above `show1ToolStripMenuItem_Click` - does it show "0 references" (or 1 fewer references than the other two?). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609657/a-backgroundworker-returning-null-without-exception-error-when-the-same-operatio?noredirect=1#comment124821148_70609657) for an indication of what I mean

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes that was the case thank you.